# Database Properties "Mirroring" Page

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am having a problem with one database on my SQL Server 2005 production server.

A number of databases are already set up for mirroring, however when I right click and go to properties in SSMS, on one particular database there is no "Mirroring" property page available.

I have done the normal tasks, such as setting Full Recovery model, running a full backup of the database and backing up the logs.

I can't see that this is a server specific issue as other databases are happily mirroring.

I've looked around and I can't see that I'm missing a setting, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is nothing to do with the Mirror Database yet, I can't get as far as specifying the Mirror Database , I cannot see the "Mirroring" page on the principle.

EDIT: I have managed to setup mirroring using t-sql commands. However I am still unable to see the "Mirroring Page".

UPDATE: This applies to the Transaction Log Shipping option as well. I can successfully set it up in SQL but not through SSMS.

Comment: Compatibility level not high enough?

Comment: Checked that thanks pal, I'm sure it must be obvious, I just can't see for looking!

Comment: Try scripting it on and see what error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to have a Microsoft Support call for the problem I was facing. Anyway after sometime and a number of support sessions they worked out that the database with the problem had an ID of 4 in sys.databases. IDs 1-4 are usually reserved for the system databases and if a database has any of these ids the T-log or Mirroring properties are not displayed. So somehow our database got the ID 3 and now I better get on and detach and reattach some databases to reassign IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Check theese items:

> 2 . The mirror database has to be created from a full backup of the principal server and should be restored in "Restore with Norecovery" model. It is followed by a restore of transaction log backup of the principal database so that the log sequence numbers of the mirror and the principal database are in synch with each other.
>   3 . The mirror database must have the same name as the principal database.
>   ...
>   8 . DB Mirroring is available in Enterprise, Developer and Standard Editions, however, please refer to Microsoft website for a comparison chart as some features are not available in the Standard Edition. SQL Server Workgroup and Express Editions can only be used as witness servers.
>   [Database Mirroring in Microsoft SQL Server 2005](http://aspalliance.com/1388_Database_Mirroring_in_Microsoft_SQL_Server_2005.2)

Test monitoring with [sp_dbmmonitorresults (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366320.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but I ran across the same symptom yesterday, and I remembered your question here, hahaha.  My problem was that I set up database mirroring using the wizards, but one of the systems had a firewall blocking the mirroring port.  The wizard setup went all the way to the final part of enabling database mirroring, and then errored out - but at that point, mirroring was already set up.  Mirroring worked great, but there was something in the database metadata that wasn't set quite right.  Even when I removed the firewall, parts of SSMS acted as if mirroring wasn't set up for that particular database, even though it was.

I then set up additional databases for mirroring (with the firewall off) and they worked great.  My solution was to remove mirroring on that database and then add it again, and it worked fine.  Doesn't sound like that's worked for you, though.